# How to remove duplicates from an array without removing the whole row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I am looking for earthquake detections as well as P and S waves. Once these parameters have been found, I store them in different tables: one for the detections, one for the P waves, and one for the S waves.

```
for i_sta in range(len(List_dir)):
    
    file = List_dir[i_sta]
    
    st = read(file)
    
    day = st[0].stats.starttime

    print(day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    
#-----------------
# Processing
#-----------------
    
    st.detrend()
    st.filter('bandpass', freqmin = 1, freqmax = 45, zerophase = 'True')
    
#-------------------------------------------
# Filter the trace for alternative plotting
#-------------------------------------------
    
    stfilt = st.copy()
    stfilt.filter('bandpass', freqmin = 1, freqmax = 15, zerophase = 'True')
    
#--------------------
# Model annotations
#--------------------
    
    annotations = model.annotate(st, strict = False)   # Returns data with annotations
    print(annotations)
    

#------------------------
# Picks and detections
#------------------------
    
    picks, detections = model.classify(st, detection_threshold = 0.9, P_threshold = 0.6, S_threshold = 0.6)   # Returns a list of picks and detections

    print("Picks:")
    for pick in picks:
        print(pick)

    print("\nDetections:")    
    for detection in detections:
        print(detection)
        
    #if picks and detections:
        
#----------------------------------------------------------
# Next lines to uncomment for writing results into a file
#----------------------------------------------------------   

    
    for detection in detections:
        A.append({
            "Date": day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
            "Start_detection": detection.start_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
            "End_detection": detection.end_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
            "Detection_probability": detection.peak_value,
        })
            
    for pick in picks:
        if pick.phase == 'P':
             B.append({
                 "Date": day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                  "P_time": pick.start_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
                  "P_probability": pick.peak_value,
             })
        else:
             C.append({
                 "Date": day.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                 "S_time": pick.start_time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),
                 "S_probability": pick.peak_value,
            })
    
    print("===============")
        
    del picks, detections, st, file
```

Once these tables are obtained, I merge these 3 tables to obtain a final table containing all the seismic events found. For this, I use pd.merge.

```
A = pd.DataFrame(A)
B = pd.DataFrame(B)
C = pd.DataFrame(C)
all_evt = pd.merge(pd.merge(A, B, how ='left'), C, how = 'left')
```

However, when I look at the final table, there are duplicates. More precisely, duplicates are created for the days when there are several detections or P/S waves detected.

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can get rid of these duplicates without removing the whole line?

What I would like to have is a table where the detections and P/S waves detected at the same time (day and hour) are on the same line and, if no detection or P/S wave S are detected, NaN would appear. Here is the expected result:
[image]

I have already tried all the features of pd.merge, without success. Then I looked at Dataframe.join or even pd.concat, but I didn't get a correct result.

Thanks in advance :)

Here is a reproducible example :

```
# --------------------------
# Writing results in lists
#---------------------------

A = [{'Date': '2020-09-23',
  'Start_detection': '08:01:52',
  'End_detection': '08:01:56',
  'Detection_probability': 0.9995621},
 {'Date': '2020-10-28',
  'Start_detection': '10:53:19',
  'End_detection': '10:53:23',
  'Detection_probability': 0.9973672},
 {'Date': '2020-10-29',
  'Start_detection': '11:12:18',
  'End_detection': '11:12:21',
  'Detection_probability': 0.9061912},
 {'Date': '2020-10-29',
  'Start_detection': '11:27:37',
  'End_detection': '11:27:42',
  'Detection_probability': 0.9933528},
 {'Date': '2020-10-29',
  'Start_detection': '11:47:18',
  'End_detection': '11:47:33',
  'Detection_probability': 0.9660959},
 {'Date': '2020-11-23',
  'Start_detection': '16:19:03',
  'End_detection': '16:19:06',
  'Detection_probability': 0.9979086}]

B = [{'Date': '2020-09-23', 'P_time': '08:01:52', 'P_probability': 0.7567052},
 {'Date': '2020-10-29', 'P_time': '11:12:17', 'P_probability': 0.6098999},
 {'Date': '2020-11-23', 'P_time': '16:19:03', 'P_probability': 0.8836917},
 {'Date': '2020-11-23', 'P_time': '19:21:58', 'P_probability': 0.8364198}]

C = [{'Date': '2020-09-23', 'S_time': '08:01:55', 'S_probability': 0.75159454},
 {'Date': '2020-11-23', 'S_time': '16:19:05', 'S_probability': 0.8108436},
 {'Date': '2020-11-23', 'S_time': '16:19:14', 'S_probability': 0.6465341},
 {'Date': '2020-11-23', 'S_time': '19:22:01', 'S_probability': 0.71296066}]

#------------------------------
# Convert data into dataframes
#------------------------------

A = pd.DataFrame(A)
B = pd.DataFrame(B)
C = pd.DataFrame(C)

#-------------------
# Merge dataframes
#-------------------
all_evt = pd.merge(pd.merge(A, B, how ='left'), C, how = 'left')
all_evt
```

Comment: You should ask you question in English only

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as raw text please?

Comment: Yes, I will try to do that !

Comment: @ArleneMorel. Try `all_evt.to_dict('list')`

Comment: I put a reproducible example as asked ! :) I will try your solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overestimating what [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) can do here. At the moment it merges on all columns that have the same name in the DataFrames A and B, which is column Date. You could be more specific with `pd.merge(A, B, on=['Date', ...])`. What I understand you want to do is merge on `Date` and `Start_detection < P_time < End_detection`. As I don't think this is possible with `pd.merge` or any pandas function, here two other ways to approach this:

**Number 1:**

I would already add all the events to the DataFrame A in the `for pick in picks` loop. Write a function that filters DataFrame A to the date of the event and for `Start_detection < P_time < End_detection` and write to this row. If no row matches add a new row. You can sort the DataFrame afterwards on `Date` and `Start_detection`.

MWE building on DataFrame A as above and writing data of P to this dataframe:

```py
P_picks = [{'day': '2020-09-23', 'start_time': '08:01:52', 'peak_value': 0.7567052},
 {'day': '2020-10-29', 'start_time': '11:12:17', 'peak_value': 0.6098999},
 {'day': '2020-11-23', 'start_time': '16:19:03', 'peak_value': 0.8836917},
 {'day': '2020-11-23', 'start_time': '19:21:58', 'peak_value': 0.8364198}]

def create_mask(df, day, time):
    mask = pd.DataFrame({
        'date': df['Date'] == day,
        'start': df['Start_detection'] <= time,
        'end': time < df['End_detection'],
    })
    return mask.all(axis='columns')

for pick in P_picks:
    mask = create_mask(A, pick['day'], pick['start_time'])

    if mask.any():
        A.loc[mask, 'P_time'] = pick['start_time']
        A.loc[mask, 'P_probability'] = pick['peak_value']
    else:
        row = {
            'Date': pick['day'],
            'P_time': pick['start_time'],
            'P_probability': pick['peak_value'],
        }
        A = pd.concat([A, pd.DataFrame(row, index=[0])], ignore_index=True)
```

Leading to this final DataFrame A:

[image: Final pd.DataFrame A]

**Number 2:**

Do as in your example, but then in `all_evt` replace all values in `P_time` and `P_probability` with `NaN` where `Start_detection > P_time` or `End_detection < P_time`.
Accounting for events that do not fall into a range will be difficult I guess. Maybe use a [split-apply-combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#flexible-apply) approach and do this per date?

Comment: Hi ! First of all, thank you for your answer ! I tried to apply the solution Number 1 and, to do so, I combined all the events in a single DataFrame A. However, I don't understand the part where I have to create the filter and the rest. I tried to use DataFrame.filter(), DataFrame.groupby(), and DataFrame.where() to replace the values I want by NaN but it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: I added a an example building on your example data to show how to write the values into the "filtered" rows.

Comment: Thank you for that ! I will try to add a filter of this sort. :)